# using composer and autoload in wordpress theme, 'Failed opening required'

Tags: php, wordpress, composer-php, themes

So I've installed createsend-php for my theme via composer (I'm trying to learn how too use it) but can't get to the next stage.

I can see the API here -
`/wp-content/themes/wonkhe2-theme/vendor/campaign-monitor/createsend-php/`

composer file seems right to me -

```
  "require": {
    "php": ">=5.4.0",
    "composer/installers": "~1.0",
    "campaignmonitor/createsend-php": ">=6.0"
  }
```

in /wp-content/themes/wonkhe2-theme/templates/content-signup-cm.php I've added
`require_once 'csrest_campaigns.php'`

And that returns

```
Fatal error: require_once(): Failed opening required 'csrest_campaigns.php' (include_path='.:/Applications/MAMP/bin/php/php7.2.7/lib/php') in /wp-content/themes/wonkhe2-theme/templates/content-signup-cm.php on line 5
```

Should the require_once path be different? I thought autoloader would set the paths and namespaces.

Using composer is new to me so apologies if I'm misunderstanding but any help appreciated.

Comment: https://getcomposer.org/doc/01-basic-usage.md#autoloading

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you should not require individual classes insalled by composer. instead, right at the start of your code:

```
require_once 'vendor/autoload.php';
```

then you can just start using objects;

```
use Some\Class\Or\Other;

$object = new Other();
```

Comment: got ya. Thanks. Needed a lil tweak `require_once  realpath(__DIR__ . '/..').'/vendor/autoload.php';`

Comment: yes, obviously the code i shown would run from site root, however decent projects would usually have their index.php in a publiuc folder :-) Can you mark this as the correct answer then please?